# Dicom Images in Matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, dicom

I need to make a matlab gui that reads and displays a directory of Dicom files.  The gui needs to have a file menu.  2. In the File menu, there is a file Open function which can read the directory of DICOM files.  I have no idea how to do this. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to get you going. You should absolutely follow [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/axes-menus-and-toolbars-in-programmatic-guis.html) link and try the code provided for yourself. I think this will greatly help you for the remainder of your project and help you understand what is going on as well.

That being said, the following creates a simple figure with an axes to display images. There is also a menu with a button used to open files, in this case DICOM files (.dcm). The hardest part is taken care of my Matlab; you only need to call a function ([uigetfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html)) in the callback of that "open" button and then call the function [dicomread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html?searchHighlight=dicomread) to read the content of a dicom file.

I'll leave the rest to you but this should help you get started.If something is unclear please don't hesitate to ask.

Code:

```
function DicomReadGUI


%// Create figure
hFigure = figure('Position',[200 200 600 600],'MenuBar','none', ...
    'Toolbar','none','HandleVisibility','callback');

%// Add an axes just to display an image.
hAxes = axes('Position',[.1 .1 .8 .8],'Parent',hFigure);

%// Add menu in which you will add the "open" button
hFileMenu      =   uimenu('Parent',hFigure,'HandleVisibility','callback','Label','File');

%// Add a button to browse and open files
hOpenMenuitem  =   uimenu('Parent',hFileMenu,...
    'Label','Open','HandleVisibility','callback', ...
    'Callback', @hOpenMenuitemCallback);


%// Callback of the "open" button
    function hOpenMenuitemCallback(hObject,eventdata)


        %// Browse the computer and select .dcm files.
        FileToRead = uigetfile('*.dcm')

        [YourImage, ColorMap] = dicomread(FileToRead);

        %// Display image in Axes1
        imshow(YourImage,'Parent',hAxes)

    end

end
```

And screenshot of the GUI with the button used to unroll a menu from which you can select files to open (circled in red):

[image]